# Have two Realms with different schema

Tags: ios, realm

In my app I have a realm for my messages and I specified another Realm for user-session storage (following some troubles we had with NSUserDefaults). The thing is that my realm for session, also has the other classes related to my messages Realm. Granted, I don't have to populate those fields in my session Realm, but it feels like there's a better way to do what I want

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: My questions was if I could exclude the tables from my message-Realm in my session-Realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to exclude tables from the Realm files your app creates, but the overhead for those empty tables is negligible.